# How To Convert Json to google visualization datatable

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, google-visualization, data-conversion

I have a method with ajax call to the server to get json result

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: '/Reports/GetJsonData',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (err) {
            alert("Error : "+err.statusText);
        }
 }).responseText;
```

Then I can get the Following Json result to the "jsonData" variable.

```
[
 {"LineName":"L1","Car":23,"Bus":0,"Motorcycle":0,"Person":0,"Others":0}
,{"LineName":"L2","Car":0,"Bus":0,"Motorcycle":6,"Person":0,"Others":0}
,{"LineName":"L3","Car":10,"Bus":20,"Motorcycle":36,"Person":13,"Others":0}
]
```

I want to convert this result to the following format

```
 [['LineName', 'Car', 'Bus','Motorcycle', 'Person','Others'],
  ['L1', 23, 0, 0,0,0],
  ['L2', 0, 0, 6,0,0],
  ['L3', 10, 20, 36,13,0]]
```

Then I want to use it in google visualization API for drawing a graph

```
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);
```

I just need to know if there any simple way to convertion the data which can pass to the google.visualization

Comment: Sounds like you want a JSON string to array in array (jagged array)?

Comment: jagged array or convert it into data table which can be used in google.visualization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = [
    {"LineName":"L1","Car":23,"Bus":0,"Motorcycle":0,"Person":0,"Others":0},
    {"LineName":"L2","Car":0,"Bus":0,"Motorcycle":6,"Person":0,"Others":0},
    {"LineName":"L3","Car":10,"Bus":20,"Motorcycle":36,"Person":13,"Others":0}
  ];

  var gglData = [];
  if (jsonData.length > 0) {
    // load column headings
    var colHead = [];
    Object.keys(jsonData[0]).forEach(function (key) {
      colHead.push(key);
    });
    gglData.push(colHead);

    // load data rows
    jsonData.forEach(function (row) {
      var gglRow = [];
      Object.keys(row).forEach(function (key) {
        gglRow.push(row[key]);
      });
      gglData.push(gglRow);
    });
  }

  // arrayToDataTable is a static method, "new" keyword not needed
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(gglData);
  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
  table.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Comment: just fyi: if you create json in the [format found here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam) -- you can create the data table directly, without client-side manipulation -- comes in handy with larger datasets...