# Array item lost when converting from array to Google Visualization DataTable

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I am calling an API that returns valid JSON data.  Google Visualization charts require that data is bound to charts from JavaScript arrays, not JSON arrays (or arrays of arrays).  Therefore using an answer I found [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226648/how-to-convert-json-to-google-visualization-datatable), I have achieved this.

It works perfectly when the JSON string contains multiple items, but for a single JSON (non-array) string, some of the data gets lost in translation.

The main part of the code is:

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"Total Users":206,"Active Users":137,"Archived Users":69}');
var arrayOfArrays = []; 
var colHead = [];

for (key in data) {
    colHead.push(key);
}
arrayOfArrays.push(colHead);
var gglRow = [];
for (key in data) {
   if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       gglRow.push(data[key]);
   }
}
arrayOfArrays.push(gglRow);
var googleDt = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayOfArrays, false);
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('MyChart'));
var options = {title: 'Test', width: 500, height: 300 };
chart.draw(googleDt, options);
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/9m2ey8uo/1/)

When the chart is rendered however, one item is always missing:

[image: Result]

I've tried multiple data sources, and one item is always missing.  A console log of `arrayOfArrays.toString()` shows all the data is there.  I can't figure out whether the issue lies with my array code, or with the chart binding...

## Solution

With thanks to @WhiteHat, the solution was to re-write the iteration code that created the Google DataTable, so that it had a 2-column format.  Rendering as a table rather than a chart made the issue obvious.

Old (incorrect) format:

[image]

New iteration code:

```
arrayOfArrays.push(["Data", "Value"]);
for (key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        arrayOfArrays.push([key, data[key]]);
    }
}
```

Result (as table - also displays well as chart):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#data-format) for a ColumnChart...

*Column 0* is used for the x-axis,
the rest for the y-axis, unless a role is specified

as such, when converting the example json,
`"Total Users"` becomes the x-axis,
and the remaining columns are plotted as...

`x=206, y=137`
`x=206, y=69`

adding another key for the x-axis resolves this issue,
see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = JSON.parse('{"Users": "Users", "Total Users":206,"Active Users":137,"Archived Users":69}');
  var arrayOfArrays = [];
  var colHead = [];

  for (key in data) {
      colHead.push(key);
  }
  arrayOfArrays.push(colHead);
  var gglRow = [];
  for (key in data) {
     if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         gglRow.push(data[key]);
     }
  }
  arrayOfArrays.push(gglRow);
  var googleDt = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayOfArrays);
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('MyChart'));
  var options = {title: 'Test', width: 500, height: 300 };
  chart.draw(googleDt, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="MyChart"></div>
```

---

note: `arrayToDataTable` is a static method, `new` keyword not required...

```
var googleDt = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayOfArrays);
```

---

**EDIT**

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages:['table']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data0 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Total Users', 30],  // <-- first row
    ['Active Users', 54],
    ['Archived Users', 80],
  ], true);  // <-- first row is data = true

  var chart0 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div0'));
  chart0.draw(data0);

  var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Group', 'Value'],  // <-- first row
    ['Total Users', 30],
    ['Active Users', 54],
    ['Archived Users', 80],
  ], false);  // <-- first row is column headings = false

  var chart1 = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
  chart1.draw(data1);
}
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div0"></div>
<div id="chart_div1"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I might struggle to implement this as I have no control over the API's output.  I will try investigate whether the Google DataTable `googleDt` allows the structure to be amended after it is created.  Also, I read that you can call the static method `arrayToDataTable(dataArray, false)` which tells it to use labels.  I can't see any documentation about this in detail, but hoped passing `true` instead  might accomplish the same...

Comment: you can _amend the structure_ of the data table by using `addColumn`, `addRow`, or several other [methods available](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods) -- the second argument in `arrayToDataTable` simply says the first row (array) is data (`true`) or column headings (`false`)...

Comment: HUGE thanks for the update.  Rendering my own code as a Table rather than chart helped me see the problem.  To fix the issue I've changed my iteration code to re-create the Google datatable in the correct 2-column format, with placeholder headers.  I will update my question with the revised code; hopefully it might help others in future.

Comment: yes, rendering as a table chart often helps me see what's going on, cheers!