# Google chart is not loading in asp.net using JSON

Tags: asp.net, json, google-visualization

I am trying to visualize data using google charts.But the chart is not displaying.I want to display data which is retrieved from sqlserver database
here is my code.

```
 <div id="chart_div" style="width:500px;height:400px">
            <%-- Here Chart Will Load --%>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

  function drawStuff() {
      var jdata = $.ajax({
          url: "GetData.aspx",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false
      }).responseText;

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jData);
      var options = {
          title: 'Chess opening moves',
          width: 900,
          legend: { position: 'none' },
          chart: {
              title: 'Chess opening moves',
              subtitle: 'popularity by percentage'
          },
          bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
          axes: {
              x: {
                  0: { side: 'top', label: 'amount' } // Top x-axis.
              }
          },
          bar: { groupWidth: "90%" }
      };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
};
</script>


        </div>
```

GetData.aspx

```
public partial class GetData : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string arr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(get(), Formatting.None,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });

            Response.Write(arr);
        }

        private object get()
        {
            List<object> ls = new List<object>();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=dell-pc;Initial Catalog=hospital;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top(5) p_id, amount from payments", con);

            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            adp.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                ls.Add(dr);
            }

            return ls;
        }
    }
```

The JsonArray loads as follows.

[{"RowError":"","RowState":2,"Table":[{"p_id":"PT1","amount":7000.0000},{"p_id":"PT2","amount":35000.0000},{"p_id":"PT8","amount":95000.0000},{"p_id":"PT10","amount":51000.0000},{"p_id":"PT3","amount":1200.0000}],"ItemArray":["PT1",7000.0000],"HasErrors":false},{"RowError":"","RowState":2,"Table":[{"p_id":"PT1","amount":7000.0000},{"p_id":"PT2","amount":35000.0000},{"p_id":"PT8","amount":95000.0000},{"p_id":"PT10","amount":51000.0000},{"p_id":"PT3","amount":1200.0000}],"ItemArray":["PT2",35000.0000],"HasErrors":false},{"RowError":"","RowState":2,"Table":[{"p_id":"PT1","amount":7000.0000},{"p_id":"PT2","amount":35000.0000},{"p_id":"PT8","amount":95000.0000},{"p_id":"PT10","amount":51000.0000},{"p_id":"PT3","amount":1200.0000}],"ItemArray":["PT8",95000.0000],"HasErrors":false},{"RowError":"","RowState":2,"Table":[{"p_id":"PT1","amount":7000.0000},{"p_id":"PT2","amount":35000.0000},{"p_id":"PT8","amount":95000.0000},{"p_id":"PT10","amount":51000.0000},{"p_id":"PT3","amount":1200.0000}],"ItemArray":["PT10",51000.0000],"HasErrors":false},{"RowError":"","RowState":2,"Table":[{"p_id":"PT1","amount":7000.0000},{"p_id":"PT2","amount":35000.0000},{"p_id":"PT8","amount":95000.0000},{"p_id":"PT10","amount":51000.0000},{"p_id":"PT3","amount":1200.0000}],"ItemArray":["PT3",1200.0000],"HasErrors":false}]

I think there is something wrong when json is loading. please help

Comment: Is that the reason I am getting the "Row Error" in my json array.because it is initially not in the database.

Comment: in order to create google's data table directly from json, the json must be in [this specific format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam) , otherwise you will need to parse the json manually on the client , similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43230905/5090771)

Comment: @WhiteHat I was using your code to manually parse the json in to the relevant format. but it gives an error :Invalid data table format: must have at least 2 columns.

Comment: was just an example, you'll need to adjust according to your format, which differs slightly...

Answer (score 1):

The main reason here that you fail to load `json` data is probably because you use a full aspx page `GetData.aspx` (and there you send wrong header, content type)

Change that to a handler, make a new handler not just rename the page, something like `getdata.ashx` and place there your code.

Be sure to send the correct content type `context.Response.ContentType`, and check that you send only the correct json data

the answers here can help : [ASP.NET Returning JSON with ASHX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392413/asp-net-returning-json-with-ashx)